# How to fetch a file from the public folder rather than trying to fetch route in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, systemjs

I'm trying to make an Angular 2 app using an existing Ruby on Rails backend, the original app is written in Angular 1.4, but now I want to start upgrading it but I can't get the app bootstrapping to work.

I have the index file inside the `app` folder, which is located outside of the `public` folder. Then I have the actual angular app inside the `public/app` folder. I did this so that I wouldn't have to use the Ruby on Rails assets pipeline.

As you can see the first script fetches the `angular2.dev.js` script successfully from the `public` folder where the angular app is located. However, the `System.import()` call is trying to fetch a route as opposed to a script file, causing a route error. As I'm new to both System and not completely into Ruby on Rails I'm having difficulties understanding how to make System fetch a file from the `public` folder rather than trying to fetch an actual route.

Any ideas?

**app/views/angular/index.html.erb**:

```
<script src="./angular2-app/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('./angular2-app/app/scripts/core/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: If you are serving the page with the rails server it will place `/public` in the web root. So if the file path on the server is `/public/foo/bar.js` then you would do `<script src="/foo/bar.js">`.

Comment: However I would just use the Rails assets pipeline - you get a cache buster, minification, etc. without the hassle of setting up a separate javascript based pipeline.